# When should I use Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have this react component (clearly simplified):

```
export class Main extends React.Component {
state = {
    home: {
      name: '',
      goals: 0
    }
}

handleInput = (name) => (value) => {
   this.setState({ [name]: value })
  }

}
```

I call handle input in my render function. Well I did until recently until I moved it out into it's own component. 
but now I fear I have bi-directional data flow:

`mainComponent` > passes `handleInput` as prop > `submitComponent` calls `handleInput` > then returns result to > `mainComponent`

This doesn't seem like the React way.

can I have some advice

my code works, no issues there but as I say doesn't seem right AND I am using Redux in my app but this seems like overkill to fire an action to the store just for the user entering one piece of data. but maybe it is right.

anyway, any pieces of advice would be appreciated

Comment: From the library author himself -  https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367 IMO I wouldn't use it until your state becomes too hard to manage.

Comment: input component can handle it's own onchange and have a submit handler to emit to the parent.

Comment: read about react-mobx

Comment: @FanCheung how do you mean? My input component is like so: `<Input onChange="functionPassedFromMain">`

Comment: <Input onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange(e)}>, there's not need to propagate it to the parent and fire back to children just for the input to change. In most cases parent only care about data upon submission, and yes using redux is overkilling

Comment: but I extracted it out because the file is getting too large...